# How do I give access to a Cloud Function so that it can access G-suite users G-mail accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gmail-api, service-accounts

**What I'm trying to do.**

I'm trying to give a Cloud Function the ability to access G-suite users G-mail accounts so that I can call the Gmail APIs watch Function on them.

**The issue**

Unable to call functions on G-suite users accounts using service account with delegated authority in a Cloud Function. Getting a 400 error back, saying Bad Request, Failed Precondition.

**What I've tried.**

I have created a Service Account in GCP by following this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) and then in G-suite, giving the service account the scope of https://mail.google.com/

I have tested accessing G-suite users gmail accounts running the code directly below on my computer successfully. I will note that GoogleCredential is deprecated so im not using this in my Cloud Function.

```
public class WatchTest {

@Test
public void callWatchOnGSuiteUsers() throws IOException {
    String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH = "/path/file.json";

    FileInputStream credentialsFile = new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_PATH);
    GoogleCredential init = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialsFile);

    HttpTransport httpTransport = init.getTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = init.getJsonFactory();

    GoogleCredential credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(init.getServiceAccountId())
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(init.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM))
            .setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")
            .build();

    Gmail gmail = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials).setApplicationName("gmail").build();

    List<String> watchTopics = new ArrayList<>();
    watchTopics.add("INBOX");

    WatchRequest watchRequest = new WatchRequest();
    watchRequest.setLabelIds(watchTopics);
    watchRequest.setTopicName("projects/{project-id}}/topics/{topic-name}}");

    gmail.users().watch("user@example.com", watchRequest).execute();
}
```

**My Cloud Function**

Deployed using:

```
gcloud functions deploy my-cloud-function 
--entry-point WatchTrigger
--service-account deletgated-authority-test@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
--runtime java11
--region <example-region>
--trigger-resource <bucket>
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

**Cloud Function Code:**

```
public class WatchTrigger implements BackgroundFunction<GcsEvent> {

@Override
public void accept(GcsEvent payload, Context context) throws Exception {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
    scopes.add(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);

    GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
            .createScoped(scopes)
            .createDelegated("user@example.com")

    HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);

    Gmail gmail = new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, requestInitializer)
            .setApplicationName("GMAIL")
            .build();

    ListLabelsResponse listResponse = gmail.users().labels().list("user@example.com").execute();

    List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
    if (labels.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No labels found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Labels:");
        for (Label label : labels) {
            System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to get a Cloud Function to do the same. From how I understand it, because I've set the service account up with domain wide delegated authority and called ServiceAccountCredentials.GetApplicationDefault() I shouldn't need to reference a credentials file in code like I did in my local test, although that may be wrong, [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-java) to my understanding of this.

When I run this code, I get back a 400 error when it tries to run the gmail.getLabels function. So I'm not really sure if the problem is with that call or the credentials.
But from what I've seen on other Stack Overflow posts similar to this, other people are getting back the same error and they are discussing the credentials as being the issue.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user@example.com/labels
{
"code" : 400,
"error" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : Precondition check failed.".
"reason" : "failedPrecondition"
} ]
```

Having a hard time understanding the way service accounts, Cloud Functions and the Gmail API work together, so if anyone can help me out on this, that would be awesome.

Thanks.

**Edit 1 - G-suite console, showing access given to Service Account.**
[image]

Comment: Do you have grant access to the service account in the gsuite console?

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks for replying :), I have added an image (Edit 1) showing what I have done in G-suite in order to give access to the Service Account. Is this what you mean by grant access? I have double checked the client ID and it matches what I have in the service account screen in GCP.